# error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k})

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi i have this Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This error is located at:
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

i know what's mean but i don't find the object in my code. I created an android application with react native and expo who name "My position". It's already publish on google play store and work very well. I want to add ads. i did it but i must add consent user to europeen people and when i add the code to consent user in my code, i obtain this error. If i delete the return at the end i don't have error but the app don't launch. my code : (i use AdsConsent from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' package)

App.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Home from './screen/Home.js';
import Rules from './screen/Rules.js';
import i18n from './i18n.js';
import 'expo-dev-client';
import { AdsConsent, AdsConsentStatus } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

export default function App() {
  async function app() {
    const consentInfo = await AdsConsent.requestInfoUpdate();

    if (consentInfo.isConsentFormAvailable && consentInfo.status === AdsConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
      const formResult = await AdsConsent.showForm();
    }
    const { storeAndAccessInformationOnDevice } = await AdsConsent.getUserChoices();

    if (storeAndAccessInformationOnDevice === false) {
        /**
        * The user declined consent for purpose 1,
        * the Google Mobile Ads SDK won't serve ads.
        */
    }
    //define variables
    const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
    const home = i18n('home');
    const rules = i18n('rulesTitle');

    //function to define screen options in Tabs.Navigator props
    function ScreenOptions({route}) {
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
        let iconName;
        let routeName = route.name;
        //define if icon is filled or outline
        if(routeName === home) {
          iconName = focused ? iconName = 'md-home' : iconName = 'md-home-outline';
        } else if (routeName === rules) {
          iconName = focused ? iconName = 'md-receipt' : iconName = 'md-receipt-outline';
        }
        return (
          <Ionicons name={iconName} color={color} size={size}/>
        )
      }
    };

    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <Tabs.Navigator
            initialRouteName={home}
            screenOptions={ScreenOptions}
          >
            <Tabs.Screen name={home} component={Home}/>
            <Tabs.Screen name={rules} component={Rules}/>
          </Tabs.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
  };
  return app();
};
```

Home.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button, Share } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import i18n from '../i18n.js';
import mobileAds, { BannerAd, TestIds, BannerAdSize } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

export default function Home() {

    //define variables and state
    const adUnitId =  __DEV__ ? TestIds.GAM_BANNER : "ca-app-pub-7771306695979114/8272761826";
    const [location, setLocation] = React.useState(null);
    const [errorMSG, setErrorMSG] = React.useState(null);
    let latitude = null;
    let longitude = null;
    let altitude = null;

    //initialize the ad load
    mobileAds()
    .initialize()

    //function to get the user location
    async function getUserLocation() {

     const {status} = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
     if(status !== 'granted') {
       setErrorMSG(i18n('permission'));
     }
     let location2 = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
     setLocation(location2);
    };

    //function to share the user location
    async function sharePosition() {
      try {
        await Share.share({
          message: i18n('message')+
          '\n'+i18n('latitude')+' : '+latitude+
          '\n'+i18n('longitude')+' : '+longitude+
          '\n'+i18n('altitude')+' : '+altitude+
          '\n https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query='+latitude+'%2C'+longitude
        })
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
      }
    };

    //define the variable text
    let text = i18n('click')+' "'+i18n('addPosition')+'"';
    if (errorMSG) {
      text = i18n('permission');
    } else if (location) {
      latitude = location.coords.latitude;
      longitude = location.coords.longitude;
      altitude = location.coords.altitude;

      text = i18n('latitude')+' : '+latitude+
           '\n'+i18n('longitude')+': '+longitude+
           '\n'+i18n('altitude')+' : '+altitude;
    };

    //define styles
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      },
      text: {
        marginTop: 100,
        marginBottom: 100,
        fontSize: 20
      }
    });
    return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                 <Button title={i18n('addPosition')} onPress={getUserLocation}/>
                 <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
                 <Button title={i18n('sharePosition')} onPress={sharePosition}/>
                 <Text>{"\n\n\n\n"}</Text>
                 <BannerAd
                    unitId={adUnitId}
                    size={BannerAdSize.ANCHORED_ADAPTIVE_BANNER}
                 />
              </View>
           )
};
```

Rules.js

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import i18n from '../i18n.js';

export default function Rules() {

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      margin: 20
    },
    text: {
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{i18n('rulesTitle')} :</Text>
      <Text>
        {i18n('rules')}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
};
```

i18n.js

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import { IntlMessageFormat } from 'intl-messageformat';

//object variable who stock the translations
const locales = {
  "fr-FR": {
           latitude: "latitude",
           longitude: "longitude",
           altitude: "altitude",
           addPosition: "Obtenir ma position",
           click : "Cliquez sur le bouton",
           sharePosition: "Partager ma position",
           home: "Accueil",
           rulesTitle: "Règles de confidentialité",
           permission: "la permission d'accès a été refusée",
           message: "Au secour ! Je suis coincé à la position indiqué par le lien ci dessous. Cliquez sur le lien pour afficher ma position dans google maps et venez me secourir svp : ",
           rules: "Cette application utilise vos données de localisation pour le fonctionnement de l'application. Ces données ne sont ni stockées ni partagées par nous mêmes à des personnes tiers. Les données sont partagées par vous mêmes aux personnes de votre choix lorsque vous utilisez l'application. \n\nCette application demande votre consentement pour utiliser vos données à caractère personnel dans les cas suivants : \n\n1) Publicités et contenu personnalisés, mesure de performance des publicités et du contenu, données d’audience et développement de produit. \n2) Stocker et/ou accéder à des informations sur un terminal. \n\nVos données personnelles seront traitées et les informations de votre appareil (cookies, identifiants uniques et autres données de l'appareil) pourront être stockées, consultées et partagées avec des fournisseurs tiers, ou utilisées spécifiquement par ce site ou cette application. \n\nCertains fournisseurs peuvent traiter vos données personnelles sur la base d'un intérêt légitime, auquel vous pouvez vous opposer en gérant vos options ci-dessous. Recherchez un lien au bas de cette page ou dans notre politique de confidentialité où vous pouvez retirer votre consentement."
        },
    "en-EN": {
           latitude: "latitude",
           longitude: "longitude",
           altitude: "altitude",
           addPosition: "Add my position",
           click: "Click on the button",
           sharePosition: "Share my position",
           home: "Home",
           rulesTitle: "Privacy rules",
           permission: "access permission has been denied",
           message: "Help ! I am stuck at the position indicated by the link below. Click on the link to display my position in google maps and come and help me please : ",
           rules: "This application uses your location data for the operation of the application. This data is neither stored nor shared by us with third parties. The data is shared by you yourself to the people of your choice when you use the application. \n\nThis application requests your consent to use your personal data in the following cases: \n\n1) Personalized ads and content, ad and content performance measurement, audience data and product development. \n2) Store and/or access information on a terminal. \n\nYour personal data will be processed and information from your device (cookies, unique identifiers, and other device data) may be stored by, accessed by and shared with third party vendors, or used specifically by this site or app. \n\nSome vendors may process your personal data on the basis of legitimate interest, which you can object to by managing your options below. Look for a link at the bottom of this page or in our privacy policy where you can withdraw consent."
        },
    "es-ES": {
           latitude:"latitud",
           longitude:"longitud",
           altitude:"altitud",
           addPosition: "Obtener mi ubicación",
           click: "clic en el botón",
           sharePosition: "Compartir mi ubicación",
           home: "Inicio",
           rulesTitle: "Reglas de confidencialidad",
           permission: "Se ha denegado el permiso de acceso",
           message: "Ayuda ! Estoy atascado en la posición indicada en el siguiente enlace. Haz clic en el enlace para ver mi posición en google maps y ven a ayudarme por favor : ",
           rules: "Esta aplicación utiliza sus datos de ubicación para el funcionamiento de la aplicación. Estos datos no los almacenamos ni los compartimos con terceros. Usted mismo comparte los datos con las personas que elija cuando utiliza la aplicación. \n\nLa aplicación solicita su consentimiento para utilizar sus datos personales en los siguientes casos: \n\n1) Anuncios y contenido personalizados, medición del rendimiento de anuncios y contenidos, datos de audiencia y desarrollo de productos. \n2) Almacenar y/o acceder a información en un terminal. \n\nSus datos personales serán procesados y la información de su dispositivo (cookies, identificadores únicos y otros datos del dispositivo) podrá ser almacenada, accedida y compartida con proveedores externos, o utilizada específicamente por este sitio o aplicación. \n\nAlgunos proveedores pueden procesar sus datos personales sobre la base de un interés legítimo, al que puede oponerse administrando sus opciones a continuación. Busque un enlace al final de esta página o en nuestra política de privacidad donde pueda retirar el consentimiento."
        },
    "de-DE": {
          latitude:"Breite",
          longitude:"Längengrad",
          altitude:"höhe",
          addPosition: "Holen Sie sich meine Position",
          click: "Klicken Sie auf die Schaltfläche",
          sharePosition: "Teile meinen Standort",
          home: "Startseite",
          rulesTitle: "Vertraulichkeitsregeln",
          permission: "Die Zugriffsberechtigung wurde verweigert",
          message: "Helfen ! Ich stecke an der im Link unten angegebenen Position fest. Klicken Sie auf den Link, um meine Position in Google Maps anzuzeigen und helfen Sie mir bitte : ",
          rules: "Diese Anwendung verwendet Ihre Standortdaten für den Betrieb der Anwendung. Diese Daten werden von uns weder gespeichert noch an Dritte weitergegeben. Die Daten werden von Ihnen selbst bei der Nutzung der Anwendung an die von Ihnen ausgewählten Personen weitergegeben. \n\nDiese Anwendung bittet Sie in den folgenden Fällen um Ihre Einwilligung zur Nutzung Ihrer personenbezogenen Daten: \n\n1) Personalisierte Anzeigen und Inhalte, Messung der Anzeigen- und Inhaltsleistung, Zielgruppendaten und Produktentwicklung. \n2) Informationen auf einem Terminal speichern und/oder darauf zugreifen. \n\nIhre personenbezogenen Daten werden verarbeitet und Informationen von Ihrem Gerät (Cookies, eindeutige Kennungen und andere Gerätedaten) können von Drittanbietern gespeichert, abgerufen und an diese weitergegeben oder speziell von dieser Website oder App verwendet werden. \n\nEinige Anbieter verarbeiten Ihre personenbezogenen Daten möglicherweise auf der Grundlage eines berechtigten Interesses, dem Sie widersprechen können, indem Sie unten Ihre Optionen verwalten. Suchen Sie unten auf dieser Seite oder in unserer Datenschutzerklärung nach einem Link, über den Sie Ihre Einwilligung widerrufen können."
        }
};

//function to translate
const i18n = (messageId, values) => {
  let locale = Localization.locale;
  if (!locales[locale]) {
      locale = 'en-EN'; // Fallback to English
    }

  const message = locales[locale][messageId];
  const formatter = new IntlMessageFormat(message, locale);
  return formatter.format(values);
};

export default i18n;
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "owner": "mg_production",
    "name": "my position",
    "slug": "my-position",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/ic_launcher.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/ic_launcher.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/ic_launcher.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.mg_production.myposition",
      "versionCode": 2
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/ic_launcher.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-localization",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "extraProguardRules": "-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.consent_sdk.** { *; }"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "c7ead926-a6f3-4db9-80ef-3596f30d421c"
      }
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-7771306695979114~3792830459",
    "delay_app_measurement_init": true
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my_position",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "expo": "^49.0.8",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.8",
    "expo-localization": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "intl-messageformat": "^10.5.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^6.4.4",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

eas.json

```
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/332kI.png)

I've been looking for the answer everywhere for 4 days and i found nothing. please help me! can you find where is the problème in the code ?

I tried everything and i found anything

Comment: You are trying to render a promise. When calling `app()` you should `await` the result. But components cannot be async, so you need to change your logic.

Comment: ok thanks, but how ? can you help me please ? how do'll you do ?

Comment: because i have to wait the user answer to launch the application. how can do this if i can't use async/await component ? How the other developper do to add user Consent ?

Comment: it's ok i found the solution. i show the ads only if the user consent.